# Launch sequence of Swift app

Tags: ios, swift

Any one knows the launch sequence of a swift app?. As i can see there is no `main` function in a swift application. Then who is responsible for doing this

```
// Entry point of a normal iOS app
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Your application object and AppDelegate is getting created here. But for swift app i was wondering who is creating these.

If any one knows, share your thoughts.

Answer (score 11):

If you look at `AppDelegate.Swift` class, you will find the `@UIApplicationMain` statement written in the global area of the file. As @Daniel also mention in his answer.

Now I tried commenting that line and compiling the code, look what I got..

[image]

In very simple language, error say compiler trying to search `implicit entry/start for main executable` , but not getting.

it shows `@UIApplicationMain` statement in `AppDelegate.Swift` creates a implicit entry point for Swift program.

And I tried to write main.swift class explicitly...it works.

my *main.swift* looks like..

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

UIApplicationMain(C_ARGC, C_ARGV, NSStringFromClass(UIApplication), NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate))
```

Comment: No autoreleasepool needed?

Comment: @CopperCash UIApplicationMain never returns, the pool can never be drained.

Answer (score 6):

the swift Book says:

> Code written at global scope is used as the entry point for the program, so you don’t need a main function.

If you have a look at your `AppDelegate` there is a marker `@UIApplicationMain` which is outside of any scope and considered as entry point.

Comment: Ya.. i have seen that. but not sure about the `@UIApplicationMain`. no docs!